# $f0 = 0$ in an Ab-cat with a zero object?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

$0 \equiv B \to 0 \to C$ in $\text{Hom}(B,C)$.  I want to show that for any map $f: C \to D$ in an **Ab**-category, $f0 =( 0: B \to D)$.

$f0 = e \neq 0 \implies f0 - e = 0$  gives me nothing.

Thank you!  Hints please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The morphism $f \circ 0$ is by definition equal to the composite $B \xrightarrow{!} 0 \xrightarrow{!} C \xrightarrow{f} D$ (where the exclamation mark means that we're considering the only existing morphism in or out of the zero object). But since a zero object is in particular initial, the composite $0 \xrightarrow{!} C \xrightarrow{!} D$ must be equal to $0 \xrightarrow{!} D$, hence $f \circ 0 = B \xrightarrow{!} 0 \xrightarrow{!} D$, which by definition is the zero map $B \to D$.

Comment: I THOUGHT something like that was going on after I posted.  You're too fast!

Comment: SO it must be true in any cat, not just **Ab**-cats.

Comment: @EnjoysMath It is true in any category with a zero object.